# Return list of Errors using ResponseEntity

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-rest

Trying to send list of `Error` in response, but in response getting only one parameter of Error type

```
Public class Error {

private ErrorEnum errorCode;
private String errorDesc;
   
}
```

Error response Method

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
@ExceptionHandler(DataNotFoundException.class)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Errors> handleResourceNotFoundException(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
        DataNotFoundException ex) {

    Error error = new Error();
    if ("POST_NOT_FOUND".equals(ex.getpostName())) {

        error.setErrorCode(Error.ErrorCodeEnum.INVALID_POST_ID);
    }

    else {

        error.setErrorCode(Error.ErrorEnum.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.add("refIdentifier", String.valueOf(ex.getpostId()));
    
    error.seterrorDesc(String.valueOf(ex.getpostId()));
    Errors errors = new Errors();
    errors.addErrorsItem(error);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(errors, httpHeaders, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

}
```

Getting error

```
  "errors": [
        {
            "errorCode": "INVALID_POST_ID"
        }
    ]
```

Errors, has list of Error and every Error has two parameters `(errorCode and errorDesc)` where errorCode is type of `Enum` in class `Error`

Any suggestion, why am getting only one parameter(`errorCode`) of `Error` class in response ?

Comment: It seems that the problem is in your getter/setter naming for `errorDesc` field. You have `seterrorDesc`, try to use `setErrorDesc` and getter `getErrorDesc`.